# Python to Postgres interface with real prepared statements?

Tags: python, postgresql

I've been trying to find a postgres interface for python 2.x that supports real prepared statements, but can't seem to find anything.  I don't want one that just escapes quotes in the params you pass in and then interpolates them into the query before executing it.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which libraries you've examined and rejected.

Answer (score 2):

Either [py-postgresql](http://python.projects.postgresql.org/) for Python3 or [pg_proboscis](http://python.projects.postgresql.org/old/project/pg_proboscis.html) for Python2 will do this.

[Python-pgsql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pgsql/) will also do this but is not threadsafe. Notably, SQLAlchemy does not make use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at web.py's [db module](http://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/db.py)

examples can be found at

1. http://webpy.org/cookbook/select
2. http://webpy.org/cookbook/update
3. http://webpy.org/cookbook/delete
4. http://webpy.org/Insert

Answer (score 0):

These links hint at the answer when using psycopg2. You don't need special API extensions.

- [Re: psycopg2 and prepared statements](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/200805051446.28085.micah@yoderdev.com)
- [Prepared Statements in Postgresql](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/2cdd1ebcad61c8e3)
- [Transparently execute SQL queries as prepared statements with

  Postgresql (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576698-transparently-execute-sql-queries-as-prepared-stat/)

Here's an example that I played with. A word of caution though, it didn't give me the expected performance increase I had hoped for. In fact, it was even slower (just slightly) in a contrived case where I tried to read the whole table of one million rows, one row at a time.

```
cur.execute('''
    PREPARE prepared_select(text, int) AS
        SELECT * FROM test
        WHERE (name = $1 and rowid > $2) or name > $1
        ORDER BY name, rowid
        LIMIT 1
''')
name = ''
rowid = 0
cur.execute('EXECUTE prepared_select(%s, %s)', (name, rowid))
```

Comment: if you had to do this inside a loop, would you call cursor.execute many times inside the loop or cursor.executemany once outside the loop?

Comment: I called cur.execute() many times inside the loop in my test. It was a contrived test comparing prepared to non-prepared. I wasn't after the fastest way to read the data.